# How to keep bar button to not scroll when uitableviewcontroller embedded in navigationcontroller

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, uitableview

I manually embed a uitableviewcontroller inside a UINavigationController, as shown below.

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
jabBookModelTableViewController *vc = [[jabBookModelTableViewController alloc]init];
vc.booksPassed = booksToPass;
vc.user = user;
navigationController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObject:vc];
vc.navigationController = navigationController;
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

My problem is that within my UITableViewController class I create a bar button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save Books"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(saveBooksAction)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
```

and if I load 30 rows in the table, and scroll down the bar button scrolls up, so the user would then have to scroll to the top to reach the button.

How do I have the UITableViewController subclass scroll, but the UINavigationController stay in one place?

Should I somehow use a UIScrollView and put my UITableViewController subclass inside the scroll view?

**UPDATE:**

I removed the property I created for `navigationController` but I got this error:

```
jabFirstViewController.m:192:33: Assignment to readonly property
```

Comment: don't you get an error/warning for `vc.navigationController = navigationController;` as navigationController in a read only property

Comment: @Moxy - No, I created my own property for this, actually, inside jabBookModelTableViewController

Comment: why do you need that property?

Comment: @Moxy - It just seemed as though it would make life easier.  So I set it and then I use it to create one of the bar buttons that I wanted.

Comment: I'm not sure but there could be some conflict. Try removing the property you declared and there's no need to assign it to your jabBookModelTableViewController (you will still be able to access it as it's a property of UIViewController) tell me if you see some change.

Comment: @Moxy - I updated with the error I got when I removed the property I added.